# meta tags in a Vue3 CSR project

Tags: vuejs3, csr

I am trying to create a product share page on Facebook or SNS in Vue3. I have tried to apply Quasar's meta tags such as ogtitle, ogdescription through meta tags, but the meta tags are dynamically generated in the code, but when I actually share them, I only read the meta tags in index.html. Is there no way to do this?

I dynamically created meta tags using Quasar meta and other libraries, but I was unable to read them from other places such as Facebook.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.